# SQL script works fine when run from SSMS, but fails syntax check when run with sqlcmd

Tags: ssms, dynamic-sql, sqlcmd

So I've got a script being used to update users on developer box SQL nodes.  It works fine in SSMS, but when I run it from sql cmd, I get an "Incorrect syntax near..." error on this line:

```
EXEC('Drop USER "' + @name + '"')
```

@name is correctly replaced with the name of the user I'm trying to drop, its throwing an error on the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  sqlcmd is either interpreting the double quotes as single quotes or ignoring them entirely.  I think the former, because if I try to run either:

```
DROP USER 'R715998-W10\MUD-CCTMRE.appool'
```

or

```
DROP USER "R715998-W10\MUD-CCTMRE.appool"
```

I get the exact same error.

Switching out the double quotes for square brackets fixed it:

```
EXEC('Drop USER [' + @name + ']')
```